# Why do we need to extend the definition of trigonometric ratios to all angles?

Tags: trigonometry, math-history

Usually (in India, at least), in 10th grade, trigonometric functions are introduced as ratios of sides of a right triangle. For example, if we have a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ such that $\angle ABC = 90^\circ = \dfrac\pi2^c$ and $\angle C=\theta$. Then, $\sin\theta = \dfrac{\mathrm{perpendicular}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}} = \dfrac{AB}{AC}$, $\cos\theta = \dfrac{\mathrm{base}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}} = \dfrac{BC}{AC}$, etc.

We notice that here, if $f$ is a trigonometric function, then $f(\alpha)$, for some angle $\alpha$ is defined only for $\alpha\in(0^\circ,90^\circ)$.

Later on, in 11th grade (again, at least in India), the unit circle definition of trigonometric functions is taught where $\sin\beta$, for example is defined $\forall~\beta\in(-\infty,\infty)$ [all angles, basically].

I want to know why we need to extend the definition of trigonometric functions to all angles. Why can't they just be defined for acute angles? I asked this from a friend of mine and he said that this definition is used multiple times in physics. But as far as I know (and most probably), the unit circle definition was given at a time when physics was not so advanced. So, why exactly did the mathematician(s) who extended the definition do so? Was this extended definition created to solve some problem that could not be solved using the right triangle definition?

Thanks!

Comment: those functions are so usefull to be limited on a finite and small domain.

Comment: @LuisFelipe True, but isn't it that those functions were used in these areas (where they became so significant) **after** this definition was given? So, why exactly was this definition given, then? I think the main thing I want to ask is "what might have been going on in the mind of the mathematician(s) who gave this definition?"

Comment: trigonometric functions are very used in complex analysis, you will see some of them on number theory, on functions related to primes, bernoulli numbers, etc. Also you will find them in fourier series. Sin and Cos are functions easy to understand so, sen(kx), cos(kx) can form a basis for a infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Comment: Some numeric approximation tehniques uses trigonometric functions, also machine learnings algorithms like SVM, PCA, etc,

Comment: @LuisFelipe Again, weren't these applications of trig functions found **after** their definition was extended. Also, AFAIK, complex analysis is a relatively new field of mathematics, much recent than trigonometry. I understand that they have a LOT of applications, though but I don't see how that answers my question...

Comment: the baisc definition comes from geometry, so you will find more applications related to geometric surfases. Also the SVM, PCA algorithms for machine learning uses the geometric approach of trigonometric functions

Comment: a better one: Outlier detection usign ABOD( angle based outlier detection) uses a lot the trigonometric concepts at basic level.

Comment: I added the tag "math-history" since it seems that OP's question isn't why it is interesting in general to extend trig functions to the whole real line, but more why it was first done historically

Comment: @LuisFelipe See, I completely understand that this extended definition has huge applications in mathematics but that unfortunately does not answer my question. The mathematicians who extended the definition could not have known that there will be so many applications in the future, could they? So, either they extended the definition for some problem to be solved or for some other reason. That problem/reason is what I want to know about. Thank you.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki So, it could simply have been done out of interest?

Comment: The idea of extension comes from trigonometric circunference. Old mathematicians noticed that if you use a circle with radius 1unit the and mark any point over the circunference, the coordinates would be $\cos,\sin$, since there are infinite points over the circunference, they  noticed that there are infinite angles with values of $\sin,\cos$, and for then, the $\tan\sec$, etc.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Right, but why could they not have left it to the first quadrant i.e. "if you make a circle with it's radius equal to one unit and it's centre at the origin, then the coordinates of the point where the terminal side of an angle $\phi$ in standard position will intersect the circle's circumference will be $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$"? Also, coordinate geometry is something Rene Descartes gave us and he was a 16th century mathematician (comparatively recent)...

Comment: Because new relations come after this, with the orientation of the angle we noticed that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$, and for example $\cos(x)=0.23, \text{ with }|x|<\pi/2$ has two solutions"!; and obviusly mathemathicians won't forget those solutions

Comment: @ Rajdeep Sindhu With new Trikonamathra applications it became necessary to define generalizations of larger angles relating them to ratio of adjoining /opposite sides in a consistent and comprehensive manner.. that was when trig was  growing as a full useful science. Necessity is the mother of invention and is so for subsequent innovations as well. How was the earth's  circumference computed so accurately if Aryabhata etal stopped the konas ( angles) at $90^{\circ}$ with the first quadrant?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry):

> Madhava (c. 1400) made early strides in the analysis of trigonometric functions and their infinite series expansions. He developed the concepts of the power series and Taylor series, and produced the power series expansions of sine, cosine, tangent, and arctangent.[24][25] Using the Taylor series approximations of sine and cosine, he produced a sine table to 12 decimal places of accuracy and a cosine table to 9 decimal places of accuracy. He also gave the power series of π and the angle, radius, diameter, and circumference of a circle in terms of trigonometric functions. His works were expanded by his followers at the Kerala School up to the 16th century.

From the power series expansion, it is natural to consider trigonometry functions
as periodic functions defined on all of $\mathbb R$. I would think that this analytic point of view (as opposed to the geometric point of view where it might make more sense to limit to $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$) is what you're asking about. It seems the motivation for the Taylor series expansion was a way to compute numerically trigonometric values.

---

Edit:

Power series expansions are particular formulas for expressing some special functions such as $\sin$, $\cos$, but also $\exp$ or $\ln$. They are useful for computing approximate values for instance, or to do other computations such as differentiating or integrating. At the beginning of calculus (with Newton and Leibniz in Europe), analysis was at first mostly concerned with such functions.

Comment: I'm sorry. Being a 10th grader, I don't know much (or anything at all) about power series, Taylor series, etc. Where can I understand them to such a level that I'm capable to understand your answer? (Do I even need to know what they mean to understand your answer, though?)